# Mixed content: socket.io in laravel on AWS

Tags: javascript, laravel, amazon-web-services, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an issue with mixed content. When I'm trying to use socket.io with laravel on AWS Elastic Beanstalk the following error occurs every 5 seconds or so (in the console):

> polling-xhr.js:272 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mypage.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://mypage.com:7000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NdlasTp'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

so it seems like it is loaded on HTTP insted of HTTPS. However in my app.js file I'm declaring it as HTTPS:

```
var server = require('https').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(7000, function() {
console.log('Connected 7000');
 });
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this error message? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is coming from your client-side code which is trying to connect to the socket server over HTTP

Comment: @Phil Where can I change it to HTTPS?

Comment: In your client-side code